# Gitlab CI: Mandatory labels for merge requests

Tags: git, yaml, gitlab

Is it possible to deny a merge request if there is a labels missing? I am using gitlab 9.0.2 and configured a CI (yml)

Every merge request should have exact one of these labels: major, minor, patch.
If there is a tag missing or multiple labels selected, it should not be possible to add the request or the CI should fail.

I would like to bump the version value of package.json.

Is this technically possible in gitlab?

**Detailed background info**

Several developers are pushing different commits to the repository. Sometimes they forget to bump the version value in `package.json`.

Now I think about mandatory labels only for merge requests. Those labels should give the information how the version should be bumped (major, minor or patch).

If there is no label set, the merge should not be done.

Maybe there is a completely different way how to take care about correct versioning of the repository.

Comment: What do you mean by tag? Is it a git tag on the last commit or are you referring to gitlab labels? Also the bumping of the version in package.json seems unrelated to the rest of your question. Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @Jawad You are right, I mean gitlab *labels* for the merge request. I added some more details to the post...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GitLab API and a script run in CI to fail the build if the MR doesn't have a certain label, but that's admittedly kind of a workaround. There's no way to do it in the UI at the moment.

See the docs for the Merge Request API, you can use a GET request and access the labels from there: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr